# Creating a trigger with 2 tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables
`SalesDiscount` , `Payment`. I'm trying to create a trigger to update the column `Total_Payment` in table `Payment` by doing `Total_Payment = Price * (1 - Discount)` but it couldn't be compiled.

**Edit: Another condition if `Code` in Table `Payment` is a null, then `Total_Payment = Price`.

```
CREATE TRIGGER updateTotalPayment
AFTER UPDATE OF Price ON Payment
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF (SELECT Code FROM Payment WHERE ID = :NEW.ID) IS NULL THEN
        UPDATE Payment
        SET Total_Payment = :NEW.Price
        WHERE ID = :NEW.ID;
    ELSE
        UPDATE Payment
        SET Total_Payment = :NEW.Price * (1 - (SELECT Discount
                                               FROM SalesDiscount S, Payment P
                                               WHERE S.Code = P.Code AND
                                                     P.ID = :NEW.ID)
        WHERE ID = :NEW.ID;
    END IF;
END;
```

With the query below to trigger it

```
UPDATE Payment
SET Price = 500
WHERE ID = 1;
```

SalesDiscount

| Code | Discount |
| --- | --- |
| AG31 | 0.5 |
| GW01 | 0.3 |
| OQ42 | 0.25 |

Payment

| ID | Product | Price | Code | Total_Payment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | TV | 1000 | Luck | 0 |
| 2 | Laptop | 1500 | null | 0 |
| 3 | Book | 100 | Good | 0 |

I got this error:

```
Error report -
ORA-04073: column list not valid for this trigger type
04073. 00000 -  "column list not valid for this trigger type"
*Cause:    A column list was specified for a non-update trigger type.
*Action:   Remove the column list.
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a *before* insert trigger.  You don't even need `IF`:

```
CREATE TRIGGER updateTotalPayment
BEFORE UPDATE OF Price ON Payment
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SELECT (:NEW.Price *
            COALESCE( (SELECT 1 - sd.Discount
                       FROM SalesDiscount sd
                       WHERE sd.Code = :NEW.Code 
                      ), 1
                    )
           )
    INTO :NEW.Total_Payment;
END;
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't clarify clearly that I have another condition which if `Code` is null in table `Payment`, then `Total_Payment = Price`. What should I modify if like this?

Comment: @BlueGiraffe . . . If `code` is `NULL`, the `JOIN` will fail and the `COALESCE()` returns `1` -- which does what you want.